# Join not working in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to apply join in EF Core, but it's returning wrong data.

If I run the below query in SQL Server it returns no results, its expected behavior.

```
select * from device d
inner join  store s on s.Id = d.StoreId
inner join category c on c.Id = d.CategoryId
where s.StoreName like '%dsfd%' and c.CategoryName like '%asdasdasd1%'
```

But When I try to run the similar code from the C# application for the same input values, it returns one row.

```
var serachresult = (from devices in _deviceRepository.GetAll()
join stores in _storeRepository.GetAll() on devices.StoreId equals stores.Id
join categories in _categoryRepository.GetAll() on devices.CategoryId equals categories.Id 
where

(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchInput.StoreName) ? stores.StoreName.Contains(searchInput.StoreName) : true) &&

(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchInput.CategoryName) ? categories.CategoryName.Contains(searchInput.CategoryName) : true) 

select new DeviceDetailsDto

{
    Id = devices.Id,
    DeviceName = devices.DeviceName,
    DeviceDesc = devices.DeviceDesc,
    DeviceCode = devices.DeviceCode,
    StoreId = devices.StoreId,
    CategoryId = devices.CategoryId,
    CategoryName = categories.CategoryName,
    StoreName = stores.StoreName
});
```

**Returned record**

> Id, AssetID, CategoryId, CreationTime, CreatorUserId, DeleterUserId,
> DeletionTime, DeviceCode, DeviceDesc, DeviceName, FlgActive,
> IsDeleted, LastModificationTime, LastModifierUserId, StoreId, Id,
> AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Country, CreationTime,
> CreatorUserId, DeleterUserId, DeletionTime, EmailAddress, FlgActive,
> IsDeleted, LastModificationTime, LastModifierUserId, PhoneNo,
> PostalCode, State, StoreDesc, StoreName, StoreNo, Id, CategoryDesc,
> CategoryName, CreationTime, CreatorUserId, DeleterUserId,
> DeletionTime, FlgActive, ImageName, ImagePath, IsDeleted, IsLast,
> LastModificationTime, LastModifierUserId, Level, ParentId, StoreId,
> TemplatesTypesId '3', '123123123', '21', '2018-05-14 18:02:58.480972',
> '2', NULL, NULL, 'asdasd', 'asdasd', 'asdasd', '1', '0', NULL, NULL,
> '1', '1', 'asdasdasd', 'asdasd', 'dasasd', 'sdasd', '2018-05-09
> 17:14:47.141586', '1', '0', '2018-05-10 11:48:34.897152',
> 'dasdasd@gmail.com', '0', '0', NULL, NULL, 'asdsadsa', 'dasdasd',
> 'asdas', 'dsfdsf', 'dsfd', 'fdsdf', '21', 'AASAS', 'asS', '2018-05-10
> 11:30:05.237959', '1', NULL, NULL, '0', 'img2.jpg',
> 'C:\workspace\src\Nec.Spar.Web.Host\img2.jpg', '0', '1', NULL,
> NULL, '0', '0', '1', NULL

**Update:**

**Returned record with less columns**

| Id | DeviceCode | DeviceDesc | DeviceName | StoreId | StoreName | CategoryId | CategoryName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | asdasd | 'asdasd' | 'asdasd' | '1' | dsfd | '21' | 'asS' |

Comment: Try to use .ToLower(). 
`stores.StoreName.ToLower().Contains(searchInput.StoreName.ToLower())`
and
`categories.CategoryName.ToLower().Contains(searchInput.CategoryName.ToLower())`. Even if this works: you might have a "Turkey issue" http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

Comment: @G43beli But how `.ToLower().` is going to help in this case? There is no math between asdasdasd1 and asS

Comment: Let EF print your query. Either `searchInput.StoreName` or `searchInput.CategoryName` does not contain what you expect it to.

Comment: @CodeCaster How to print query? Could you please explain your comment, its not clear to me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20751723/

Comment: What EF Core version are you on?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF Core version 2.0.1

Comment: You can add debug logging of all EF generated SQL by adding a LoggerFactory when registering the DbContext:

In Startup.cs:
public static readonly LoggerFactory DebugLoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[] { new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.DebugLoggerProvider() });

In ConfigureServices:
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"))
                .UseLoggerFactory(DebugLoggerFactory));

Generated SQL will be shown in the debug output in VS.

Comment: @viveknuna I'm afraid this is not reproducible. If you provide repro, I can take a look. Without that you are the only one who can figure out what is going on.

Comment: @IvanStoev I’m also tried IndexOf instead of Contains. It works as expected. Is this turkey issue as mentioned by G43beli in the first comment.

Comment: But `string.IndexOf` is not translated to SQL and is evaluated locally. Did you try `EF.Functions.Like`?

Comment: @IvanStoev I haven’t try ‘EF.Functions.Like’. How to use it?

Comment: Similar to SQL, e.g. instead of `stores.StoreName.Contains(searchInput.StoreName)`, try `EF.Functions.Like(stores.StoreName, "%" + searchInput.StoreName + "%")`. It's explained (sort of) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#effunctionslike).

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev I’ll try and let you know.

Comment: Any update on that? Also, it would help to see generated SQL.